# Does git only support a flat tag structure?

Tags: git, svn, version-control, git-tag

I'm moving from `svn` to `git`. With `svn` I used to have a tag structure like this:

```
tags
| fixes
| | 14
| | 31
| | 46
| betas
| | 1.1b
| | 1.1b2
| releases
| | 1.0
| | 1.1
| | 1.2
```

Is this not possible with `git`? Every `git` documentation I've read only mentions simple flat tagging with names, but no hierarchical structure:

```
$ git tag
v1.0
v1.1
v1.2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put `/` in your Git tag names, so you can:

```
git tag fixes/14
git tag betas/1.1b
```

Et cetera.  I would consider it kind of redundant since it's already obvious that `1.1b` is a beta.

Please note that Git tags and Subversion tags are very different.  A Git tag is a named point in history, whereas a Subversion tag is a directory.  As a consequence, you can browse Git tags with history tools like `gitk`, so you may discover that you have no need for hierarchical names.

Comment: **"A tag is just a “snapshot” of a project in time. In Subversion, this idea already seems to be everywhere."** What do you mean by "subversion tag is a directory"? Looks like you don't understand the concept behind SVN branches and tags. See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.whatis.html and TAGS reference at http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.tags.html

Comment: @bahrep: Correct me if I'm wrong, but can't you modify a tag in Subversion just like any other part of your repository?

Comment: you can, but then it's not a "tag" anymore. **Tag is a named snapshot, a symbolical connection with the specified revision of a project.**

Comment: @bahrep: That's exactly my point.  Git tags are implemented differently.

Comment: @bahrep: For example, I'd also say that branches in Git and Mercurial are very different.  They seem similar on the surface, but they behave in different ways.

Comment: I just tried gitk. I would have a difficult time finding a less user friendly tool.

Answer (score -4):

Please read docs!

Let me quote a good paragraph of [TortoiseSVN Manual](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-branchtag.html) that explains the concept behind tags in Apache Subversion (as well as branches btw).

> Subversion does not have special commands for branching or tagging,
>   but uses so-called “cheap copies” instead. Cheap copies are similar to
>   hard links in Unix, which means that instead of making a complete copy
>   in the repository, an internal link is created, pointing to a specific
>   tree/revision. As a result branches and tags are very quick to create,
>   and take up almost no extra space in the repository.

Tags are also described in [SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.tags.html).

Comment: I know how svn tags work. I've read the red book. But this was not my question.